# Trying to install ros-ROS_DISTRO-behaviortree-cpp-v3 in ROS 2 Iron

Tags: ros2

I get an error

> you have held broken packages.

[image: snap shot of terminal]

Comment: Please paste errors as text and not as screen shots. Images are not text-searchable.

Comment: Sorry it took me this long to get back to you, I tried apt-mark showhold,this comes back with no errors and sudo apt-get install aptitude, shows that I already have the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of the error is

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

You need to fix the broken packages - but you can't do that whilst they are *held*.

To list the held packages

```
apt-mark showhold
```

Then *unhold* them by

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

Now you can remove the conflicting package (i.e. `libcom-err2`) and then reinstall all.

Or you could use [aptitude](https://askubuntu.com/a/451078/16395) - if you need to install it

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Either way, double check *carefully* any commands and any packages marked for removal.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass the error by building using sources
clone v3.8 branch of Behavior tree cpp and build it
It is really hard that they do not have deb of iron version